# Xcode 7.0.1 bug or there is a solution?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, orientation, share

I made an app in Xcode 6.1, it was approved by apple, no issues. I updated to Xcode 7.0.1 and now I have device orientation issue on the same app. I have same exact code for iPad and iPhone. However, when I click my Facebook button for sharing only the iPhone versions, never flip to Upside Down orientation even though i use UIInterfaceOrientationMask.

Could something like this be a bug in Xcode 7.0.1 or is Social Framework updated now for Xcode 7.0.1 or is SLComposeViewController different for iPhones for Xcode 7.0.1? I'm lost, what can be the issue?